# Migrating from Amazon S3 Storage Related Programming to GPC in MERN app

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, google-cloud-platform, mern

I'm new with MERN and Cloud beased deployement,
I have an existing project developed with MERN, that was initialy built to support AWS S3 storage, i'm trying to migrate to GCP.

Would you please confirm for me which point of below points is right:

- Does Amazon S3 Storage Related Programming needs to be changed everywhere in the code ?
- Or it needs to be changed just from AWS config files ?

Comment: Can you please clear about your use-case and what you are trying to accomplish? Also do you mean to migrate from AWS S3 to [GCS](https://cloud.google.com/storage)?

Comment: Hello, i'm trying to set up a devoops to my app, but insteas of AWS i want to use GCP, so the main question is to make my app support GCP what configuration shoullld i make,the current configuration that i have is for AWS S3

Comment: So, you want to use [Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage), am I correct?

Comment: Yes, you are, what steps should i follow to make the changes

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your use case, the Documentation below could help you in migrating from AWS S3 Storage to Cloud Storage.

Migrating from Amazon S3 to Cloud Storage

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/migrating

Creating and managing data transfers with the Console

https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/create-manage-transfer-console